# Usergroup.asmx returns "UNAUTHORIZED" for *some* groups

Tags: web-services, error, user-profile-service, soap, authorization

I am trying to invoke the "GetUserCollectionFromGroup" method of the UserGroup.asmx web service. I am using the "Web Service" function in Nintex Workflow but I am pretty confident that Nintex is not related to the problem.

When I create a SOAP envelope like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
   <soap:Header>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
     <m:GetUserCollectionFromGroup>
       <m:groupName>Admin</m:groupName>
     </m:GetUserCollectionFromGroup>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

The appropriate response is returned. Group members and their properties are listed.

When I request the group "Security" however it returns `401 UNAUTHORIZED`.

I am using a service account that has been added to the Site Owners group and I don't understand why some groups would return the list of users & their properties while others will not allow access.

I firmly believe that it is a permissions issue or a group ownership issue but I can't quite narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sharepoint groups you getting 401, try below.

Navigate to the sharepoint group settings page and set the property " Who can view the membership of the group?" to "Everyone".

Comment: You my friend are a genius. Simple solution to something that seemed overly complex!! Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Site Owners don't necessarily have the permission to enumerate all SharePoint groups -- you should be able to enumerate all groups with a farm administrator account.

Comment: Why would this group be different than the others? I have relatively limited access to this farm and I *definitely* don't want to give a service account farm admin rights.

Comment: Eh I'm fine with that -- sssreddy's answer tells you how to do what you're looking for, all I knew was that your account didn't have the access to do it when you were trying before!

Comment: You were headed down the same path :) I can't believe I gloss over simple things like this sometimes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Can we do this automatically - change " Who can view the membership of the group?" to "Everyone" in Call Web service when creating this group in nintext. By default it is set to group members.